# How to post SOAP data to server in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am trying to post data to server but it give me error 
code is

```
-(IBAction)loginBtnClk:(id)sender
{
  [self sendDataToServer :@"POST"];
}

-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method{

    int UserId=0;
    NSString *UserCode  = userTf.text;
    int RoleId=12;
    NSString *Salutation = @"Mr.";
    NSString *FirstName=frstnmetf.text;
    NSString *LastName =lstnametf.text;
    NSString *Pwd=paswrdTf.text;
    NSString *EmailId=@"abc@gmail.com";
    NSString *Mobile=@"9876543210";
    NSString *UserType=@"4";
    int EmpId=0;
    int ZoneId=575;

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%d&UserCode=%@&RoleId=%d&Salutation=%@&FirstName=%@&LastName=%@&Pwd=%@EmailId=%@&Mobile=%@&UserType=%@&EmpId=%d&ZoneId=%d",UserId,UserCode,RoleId,Salutation,FirstName,LastName,Pwd,EmailId,Mobile,UserType,EmpId,ZoneId];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[post length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL?op=Insert_UserData"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",request);
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Connection link =%@",conn);
    if(conn) {
        mutableData =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegates

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutableData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutableData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;
    return;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSXMLParser *myNSXMLParserfloorObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:mutableData];
    myNSXMLParserfloorObj.delegate=self;
    [myNSXMLParserfloorObj parse];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNSXMLParserfloorObj.parserError);
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Insert_UserData"])
    {
        myDataClassObj=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    myMutableStringObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObj);
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedict);


}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

}
```

when I am trying to post data it shows me error

```
2016-06-28 16:37:07.793 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Connection Successful
2016-06-28 16:37:13.035 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: soap:Receiver
2016-06-28 16:37:13.035 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:15.241 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---
2016-06-28 16:37:15.242 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:17.680 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: >
2016-06-28 16:37:17.680 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:19.835 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String:  System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
2016-06-28 16:37:19.835 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:21.555 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
2016-06-28 16:37:21.556 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:22.808 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
2016-06-28 16:37:22.808 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:23.810 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
2016-06-28 16:37:23.811 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:24.696 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
2016-06-28 16:37:24.696 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:25.532 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
2016-06-28 16:37:25.532 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:26.200 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
2016-06-28 16:37:26.200 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:26.986 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
2016-06-28 16:37:26.986 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:27.820 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
2016-06-28 16:37:27.820 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:28.705 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
2016-06-28 16:37:28.705 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:29.474 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean
2016-06-28 16:37:29.475 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:30.309 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: &
2016-06-28 16:37:30.309 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:31.129 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String:  abortProcessing)
2016-06-28 16:37:31.130 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:31.881 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] Array String: 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2016-06-28 16:37:31.882 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] JSON DATA = (null)
2016-06-28 16:37:31.882 WebServiceDemo[5407:137315] (null)
```

I am not getting what the issue is. Data is retrive from server properly but at the time of posting is shows me error.
help me.

Comment: For debugging purposes, it would be helpful if you could print the entire received data before parsing it. Judging from the parsed pieces, it looks as if the web service was expecting a different request, namely some XML body instead of a list of URL encoded values.

Comment: Then how to convert URL encoded values to XML body.

Comment: @"<MobileUserLogin xmlns=\"http://yoururl.com/\">\n"
         "<ApplicationId>%@</ApplicationId>\n"
         "<EmailAddress>%@</EmailAddress>\n"
         "<Password>%@</Password>\n"
         "</MobileUserLogin>\n"

Comment: @Bhadresh I tried same. But it shows me the same error.

Comment: You need information about what a valid request should look like. We cannot give you this information as this is specific to the web service and we don't know what web service you're using. @BhadreshKathiriya's comment is just a guess that's most likely wrong. Talk to whoever is responsible for the web service. They will know.

Comment: webservice is SOAP type. that is in XML format.

Comment: SOAP is a really complex type of web service. The XML for the request is huge and any simple mistake will lead to an error. First, you need to get the WSDL file (or URL). Then I propose you use a decent SOAP library like [SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine). But even that won't shield you from the complexity. You'll need to be able to read the WSDL file and understand the data structures used in the request and the response. (It's one of the major reason why people move away from SOAP/XML web services and use JSON based implementations instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' Finally run. Just I change the code

```
-(IBAction)sendDataUsingGet:(id)sender{

    [self sendDataToServer : @"GET"];
}
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method{

    int UserId=idtxt.text;
    NSString *UserCode  = userTf.text;

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<Method xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<Paramener1>%d</Paramener1>"
                             "<Paramener2>%@</Paramener2>"
                             "</Method>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",UserId,UserCode];

    NSData *postData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/Method"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",request);
    //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Connection link =%@",conn);
    if(conn) {
        mutableData =[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegates

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutableData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutableData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    serverResponse.text = NO_CONNECTION;
    return;
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSXMLParser *myNSXMLParserfloorObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:mutableData];
    myNSXMLParserfloorObj.delegate=self;
    [myNSXMLParserfloorObj parse];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNSXMLParserfloorObj.parserError);
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Insert_UserData"])
    {
        myDataClassObj=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    myMutableStringObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringObj);
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responsedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedict);


}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please be serialize the data before you will send

     NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


            NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myArray addObject:param];

            NSError * err;
            NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:0 error:&err];


            NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
            [postBody appendData:jsonData];

            //add the body to the post
            [request setHTTPBody:postBody];



    //    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
    //    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    //    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/raw"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


        //    UploadDataCmd dataCmd = (UploadDataCmd )cmd;
        //    dataCmd.resource = [MyEFAPIResource getUploadMePhotoResource:param];
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                                 initWithRequest:request];
            operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
             {
                 //[dataCmd filterData:responseObject];
                 NSLog(@"Pushed Done");
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error)
             {
                 //[dataCmd showError:error];
                  NSLog(@"Not Pushed");
             }];
            [operation start];
```

Comment: What is AFHTTPRequestOperation ??